# gwt VerticalPanel foreach

Tags: java, gwt, foreach

Is it possible to iterate a VerticalPanel and grab only certain widget.

I know you can do this with a list of string in GWT, but it doesnt work for  widgets. I like the short hand iterration, however if there is a longer method, it is welcome as well.

Task: basically determine which checkbox in that panle is selected.

this works: basic foreach
for(string i : my_list)
...
...

this wont: gwt widget
for(checkbox ch : my_vpanel)
...
...

Error I get is: cannot convert from element type Widget to CheckBox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can iterate the widgets of a ComplexPanel such as

```
for (Widget widget : verticalPanel) {
    //Do stuff
}
```

or

```
Iterator<Widget> it = verticalPanel.iterator();
while(it.hasNext()){
    Widget widget = it.next();
    //Do stuff
}
```

or

```
for (int i=0;i<verticalPanel.getWidgetCount();i++){
    Widget widget = verticalPanel.getWidget(i);
    //Do stuff
}
```

and to see if a Widget is a type of CheckBox you can use

```
if (widget instanceof CheckBox){
    CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) widget;
}
```

Comment: Thanks this is what I was looking for, instanceof. I assumed within my original for loop that type casting would be handled automatically, and cast each widget if they were checkbox. But this really helped.